# PowerMockito and CORBA conflict

Tags: java, testing, junit, powermock, corba

I am trying to use PowerMockito for doing some testing on a project which uses a third party library which uses CORBA. I am trying to skip this exception by finding the source of the problem. I didn't succeed to find information about this matter.

This is the simplest code that I can't make it work:

Java class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ORBTest {

    @Test
    public void initORB() throws Exception {
        ORB.init();
    }    
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Log.error

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: 
when resolving method "sun.corba.EncapsInputStreamFactory.newEncapsInputStream(Lorg/omg/CORBA/ORB;[BI)Lcom/sun/corba/se/impl/encoding/EncapsInputStream;" the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/corba/se/impl/ior/ObjectKeyFactoryImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, sun/corba/EncapsInputStreamFactory, have different Class objects for the type /CORBA/ORB;[BI)Lcom/sun/corba/se/impl/encoding/EncapsInputStream; used in the signature
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.ior.ObjectKeyFactoryImpl.create(ObjectKeyFactoryImpl.java:222)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.<init>(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:59)
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.resolver.ResolverDefault.makeBootstrapResolver(ResolverDefault.java:75)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBConfiguratorImpl.initializeNaming(ORBConfiguratorImpl.java:419)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBConfiguratorImpl.configure(ORBConfiguratorImpl.java:151)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.postInit(ORBImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.set_parameters(ORBImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBSingleton.getFullORB(ORBSingleton.java:453)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBSingleton.getORBData(ORBSingleton.java:632)
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.ORB.getLogger(ORB.java:477)
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.ORB.getLogWrapper(ORB.java:523)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.get(ORBUtilSystemException.java:54)
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.ORB.<init>(ORB.java:281)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBSingleton.<init>(ORBSingleton.java:135)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:292)
    at org.test.test.MockitoTest.test(MockitoTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:144)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I'd appreciate if someone could shed me some light here since y don't know what to change to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors like this

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: 
>   when resolving method ... previously initiated loading for a different type with name...

Usually could be resolved by adding class or package that contains a method to `@PowerMockIgnore`.

In your case, I'd recommend try add to test 
`@PowerMockIgnore("org.omg.CORBA.ORB")`

[Javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.5/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PowerMockIgnore.html)